# .vbs to stop .bat being run past a certain time

Tags: time, vbscript

I have a scheduled task which runs on my server to put 2 other desktop machines asleep at 2am.

I also have a .bat file scheduled to run at 1:40am on all of my systems to let me know of the impending shutdown operation and give me the option to cancel, standby immediately or close the window and allow it to proceed. Works fine on all systems except a Win7 Laptop.

Despite me having the task set not to run past it's scheduled time, if I open my laptop and it resumes from standby any time after 2am, the file will still run.

I wanted to try and create a workaround by scheduling a .vbs to launch the .bat instead. Along the lines of:

```
if Hour(Time) > 1 Then
wscript.quit
else if Hour(Time) = 1 Then
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cancel-confirm-autostandby.bat C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", 1
end if
wscript.quit
```

But the .bat file runs regardless, even testing now at 3am. If I try;

```
msgbox Hour(Time)
```

It returns a value of 3, so I don't understand this behavior. 3 is > than 1...

I have tried assigning the cutoff time (2am) to a varible tried Hour(Now) & Hour(Date).

Any suggestions welcome, thank you for reading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have got it with

```
if Hour(Time) > 1 Then
wscript.quit
else if Hour(Time) = 1 Then
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "cancel-confirm-autostandby.bat C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe", 1
end if
wscript.quit
End if
```

Don't know why it wouldn't work with just the second last "End if", but there you go...